# R: simpler ways of splitting columns and getting sums of category values

Tags: r, string, sum, delimiter

I have a data frame in which each a row is an observation, the last column is called 'overlaps' and shows observations from a different dataset which occur at the same time as the observations in this data frame.

The results I have come from [a question I previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74924471/pulling-values-of-co-occuring-over-lapping-time-data-in-r/74928064?noredirect=1#comment132340266_74928064) about how to get overlapping data out of a data frame.

All of these overlapping observations have been concatenated together into a single column as such:

```
 [1] "1_hands:N:1.768,1_hands:N:3.343,2_body:N:14.272"                                                                                                                                  
 [2] "1_hands:CH2:4.021,2_body:N:14.272"                                                                                                                                                
 [3] "1_hands:N:1.862,2_body:N:4.825"                                                                                                                                                   
 [4] "1_hands:CH2:1.978,2_body:N:4.825,2_body:CH1:1.075"                                                                                                                                
 [5] "1_hands:CH1:0.821,1_hands:N:1.417,1_hands:N:2.213,2_body:N:5.485"                                                                                                                 
 [6] "1_hands:CH1:3.557,2_body:N:3.519"                                                                                                                                                 
 [7] "1_hands:CH1:3.557,1_hands:N:1.249,2_body:N:3.519"                                                                                                                                 
 [8] "1_hands:CH1:4.896,2_body:CH1:3.308"                                                                                                                                               
 [9] "1_hands:CH1:4.896,2_body:CH1:3.308,2_body:N:1.67"                                                                                                                                 
[10] "1_hands:CH1:4.896,2_body:N:1.67,2_body:CH1:5.288"
```

Each observation is separated by ",". The ":" separates different elements of the observation. For example the observation:

1_hands:N:1.768

would divided up as such:

1_hands = category

N = value

1.768 = duration

What I want to do, is get the sum total duration of each category and value, essentially, I want to add up the durations of every "1_hands:N:X".

One way to do this is with the stringr package, I can use the various str_split functions to continuously break down the observations by delimiters "," and ":", to finally get a column of just the duration values of a particular category and value, which I could then get the sum total of.

However, it's monstrously inefficient, and I have to do this for multiple data sets.

Is there an easier way to do this? Is it possible to loop through that data as such to just get the sum totals I need without breaking it down into multiple sets of data frames?

Comment: So when you say "monstrously" inefficient, are you saying it runs slowly? What type of performance are you getting and what type of performance do you need? You have data in a non-standard format for parsing and it needs to be cast to numeric data types for adding. There may be other ways to extract that data but it would be useful to have a baseline measurement to see if it's any faster. Here is the code you have already tried? Maybe there are ways to improve your existing code.

Comment: What exactly is the desired output for this sample input. Is it just one number?

Comment: It's in inefficient in that there are a lot of lines of code to copy and paste, and makes my script very long, and kind of difficult to keep track of, even using # to organize things.

The desired output would just be a sum of all the numerical values attached to a given observation. Thus if I have the following observations that can be found throughout various rows in the column:

1_hands:N:1.5
1_hands:N:1.877
1_hands:N:3.57

I'd just want a number that is the sum of those numerical values, which, in this example would be 6.947

Comment: and yes, my code that produced this data in the first place would very well be improved, here is source from which my code is drawn: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74924471/pulling-values-of-co-occuring-over-lapping-time-data-in-r/74928064?noredirect=1#comment132340266_74928064

Comment: So you want one number for "1_hands" and a separate number for "2_body"? Or do you only want a value for "1_hands" even when other values are present? I'm not sure what you are copy/pasting. Seems like you should be able to make a reusable function. I can't tell what you are doing from the link you provided. It's not clear to me which part of that question/answer you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exact efficiency you are trying to achieve, but this solution should be reasonably fast

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

df1 <- your_data[1:5,1]
df2 <- your_data[6:10,1]

myFun <- function(data){
  temp <- data.table(vars = data)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ",", fixed = TRUE)))] %>% na.omit()
  temp <- setDT(tstrsplit(temp$vars, ":", fixed = TRUE, names = c("category", "value", "duration")))
}

dt <- list(df1, df2) %>%
  purrr::map(~ myFun(.x)) %>%
  rbindlist()
dt <- dt[, duration := as.numeric(duration)]

dt_sum <- dt[,.(durSum = sum(duration)), by = c("category", "value")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code

### data

```r
df <- data.frame(string=c("1_hands:N:1.768,1_hands:N:3.343,2_body:N:14.272",
                          "1_hands:N:1.768,1_hands:N:3.343,2_body:N:14.272",                                                                                                                                  
                          "1_hands:CH2:4.021,2_body:N:14.272",                                                                                                                                                
                          "1_hands:N:1.862,2_body:N:4.825",                                                                                                                                                   
                          "1_hands:CH2:1.978,2_body:N:4.825,2_body:CH1:1.075",                                                                                                                                
                          "1_hands:CH1:0.821,1_hands:N:1.417,1_hands:N:2.213,2_body:N:5.485",                                                                                                                 
                          "1_hands:CH1:3.557,2_body:N:3.519",                                                                                                                                                 
                          "1_hands:CH1:3.557,1_hands:N:1.249,2_body:N:3.519",                                                                                                                                 
                          "1_hands:CH1:4.896,2_body:CH1:3.308",                                                                                                                                               
                          "1_hands:CH1:4.896,2_body:CH1:3.308,2_body:N:1.67",                                                                                                                                 
                          "1_hands:CH1:4.896,2_body:N:1.67,2_body:CH1:5.288"))
```

### code

```r
df %>% 
  tidyr::extract(string, into = c('category','value','duration'), regex = '(.*):(.*):(.*)') %>% 
  group_by(category, value) %>% summarise(duration=sum(as.numeric(duration)))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### output

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   category [2]
  category value duration
  <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
1 1_hands  CH1      22.6 
2 1_hands  CH2       6.00
3 1_hands  N        17.0 
4 2_body   CH1      13.0 
5 2_body   N        68.3
```

Comment: this didn't quite work for me, I tried with the data and code exactly as you provided it here, but my output was different, it gave me 10 rows, and the first column looks like this:

category                                                 
   <chr>                                                  
 1 1_hands:CH1:0.821,1_hands:N:1.417,1_hands:N:2.213,2_body         
 2 1_hands:CH1:3.557,1_hands:N:1.249,2_body

Comment: Could you please provide more details of the exact data, to update the code